# Compute "concentration" of pandas categoricals

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a problem with an old function computing the concentration of pandas categorical columns. There seems to have been a change making it impossible to subset the result of the `.value_counts()` method of a categorical series.

Minimal non-working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["a","b","c","a"]})

def get_concentration(df,cat):
    tmp = df[cat].astype("category")
    counts = tmp.value_counts()
    obs = len(tmp)
    all_cons = []
    for key in counts.keys():
        single = np.square(np.divide(float(counts[key]),float(obs)))
        all_cons.append(single)
        return np.sum(all_cons)

get_concentration(df, "A")
```

This results in a key error for `counts["a"]`. I'm quite sure this worked in a past version of pandas and the documentation doesn't seem to mention a change regarding the `.value_counts()` method.

Comment: I've added a simplified and vectorized version that also doesn't require `categorical` `dtype`.

Comment: Amongst other issues, the return statement should be outside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're iterating in a loop (and not working vectorically), you might as well just explicitly iterate over pairs. It simplifies the syntax, IMHO:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["a","b","c","a"]})

def get_concentration(df,cat):
    tmp = df[cat].astype("category")
    counts = tmp.value_counts()
    obs = len(tmp)
    all_cons = []
    # See change in following line - you're anyway iterating 
    #    over key-value pairs; why not do so explicitly?
    for k, v in counts.to_dict().items():
        single = np.square(np.divide(float(v),float(obs)))
        all_cons.append(single)
        return np.sum(all_cons)

>>> get_concentration(df, "A")
0.25
```

Comment: This seems to be the most natural solution! Thanks :)

Comment: @Matthias You're very welcome. I'd recommend, however, that you view loops in numerical code as a "red flag".

Answer (score 2):

Let's agree on methodology:

```
>>> df.A.value_counts()
a    2
b    1
c    1

obs = len((df['A'].astype('category'))
>>> obs
4
```

The concentration should be as follows (per the [Herfindahl Index](http://www.investopedia.com/exam-guide/cfa-level-1/equity-investments/concentration-ratio-herfindahl-index.asp)):

```
>>> (2 / 4.) ** 2 + (1 / 4.) ** 2 + (1 / 4.) ** 2
0.375
```

Which is equivalent to (Pandas 0.17+):

```
>>> ((df.A.value_counts() / df.A.count()) ** 2).sum()
0.375
```

If you really want a function:

```
def concentration(df, col):
    return ((df[col].value_counts() / df[col].count()) ** 2).sum()

>>> concentration(df, 'A')
0.375
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the current function, you just need to access the `index` values using `.ix` (see below). You might be better of using a vectorized function - I've addend one at the end.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["a","b","c","a"]})

tmp = df[cat].astype('category')
counts = tmp.value_counts()
obs = len(tmp)
all_cons = []
for key in counts.index:
    single = np.square(np.divide(float(counts.ix[key]), float(obs)))
    all_cons.append(single)
    return np.sum(all_cons)
```

yields:

```
get_concentration(df, "A")

0.25
```

You might want to try a vectorized version, which also doesn't necessarily need the `category` `dtype`, such as:

```
def get_concentration(df, cat):
    counts = df[cat].value_counts()
    return counts.div(len(counts)).pow(2).sum()
```